# host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Tags: django, postgresql, docker

I'm trying to set up a Django website that connects to the "default" PostgreSQL db, all within Docker. Note, I'm trying to db inside the postgres image.
After running the `docker-compose up --remove-orphans` command, the error within the title is executed. Can I do anything to fix this?

What I am currently using is:

Settings.py - DATABASES

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7-slim as production

ENV PYTHONUNBEFFERED=1
WORKDIR /app/

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    bash \
    build-essential \
    gcc \
    libffi-dev \
    musl-dev \
    openssl \
    postgresql \
    libpq-dev

COPY requirements/prod.txt ./requirements/prod.txt
RUN pip install -r ./requirements/prod.txt

COPY manage.py ./manage.py
COPY website ./website

EXPOSE 8000

FROM production as development

COPY requirements/dev.txt ./requirements/dev.txt
RUN pip install -r ./requirements/dev.txt

COPY . .
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"

x-service-volumes: &service-volumes
  - ./:/app/:rw,cached

x-database-variables: &database-variables
  POSTGRES_DB: postgres
  POSTGRES_USER: postgres
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres

x-app-variables: &app-variables
  <<: *database-variables
  POSTGRES_HOST: postgres

services:
  website:
    image: "django_image:latest"
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes: *service-volumes
    environment: *app-variables
    depends_on:
      - db_migrate
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"

  db_migrate:
    image: "django_image:latest"
    command: python manage.py migrate
    volumes: *service-volumes
    environment: *app-variables
    depends_on:
      - postgres

  postgres:
    image: "postgres:latest"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment: *database-variables
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgres

volumes:
  db-data:
```

Comment: Your `settings.py` file needs to look at `os.getenv('POSTGRES_HOST')` to find the database host.  It's currently pointing at `localhost`, which in Docker typically means "the current container".

Comment: You nailed it! Indeed I do not know why my question was closed with an answer that is not solving my problem, which is substituting HOST with "postgres",  indeed this was creating me other problems with commands like 'makemigrations' and 'createsuperuser'. Instead, using os.getenv('POSTGRES_HOST') in settings.py is solving everything! Can you tell me why the other solution is not working? Thanks man!

Comment: The database host name will be different from inside a container and outside.  In a container you need to use normal [Docker networking](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) and the database host name will usually be the Compose service name of the database container; outside a container, it will be the physical system's host name, or `localhost` if you're developing on the same system as the containers.  There are many many questions that center on incorrectly hard-coding `localhost` as the database hostname and it not working in Docker.